# Complexity of finding the maximum sum divided by product

Tags: computational-complexity, combinatorial-optimization

What is the complexity of the following optimization problem?

**Problem.**
Given $n$ pairs of positive reals $(a_i,b_i)_{i=1}^n$, choose a subset $S \subseteq [n]$ to maximize
$$
\frac{\sum_{i\in S} a_i}{\Pi_{i\in S} b_i}.
$$
How do we efficiently solve it?  Or is it NP-hard? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just take $b_1=0$?

Comment: @Chris: I'm guessing that the numbers $a_i$ and $b_i$ are provided and one has to find the best $S$. It doesn't seem trivial to me and I wish people voting to close would explain themselves.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay: I agree and I think the MO approach is to consider your and my comments as votes against closing, so the next two people who want to vote to close should instead leave comments canceling out our votes against closing.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for the comments and answers. After posting this question, I thought it for a while. It may be NP-complete. Please see the outline of my proof.

**Partition**: given positive integers $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$, find a subset $S$ such that 
$$
\sum_{i\in S} a_i = 1/2 \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n a_i.
$$

Let $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i =2K$. We set $b_i$ as follows: $b_i=e^{a_i/K}$ for each $i$. Then, for each subset $S$,
$$
\frac{\sum_{i\in S} a_i}{\Pi_{i\in S} b_i}= \sum_{i\in S} a_i \cdot e^{-\sum_{i\in S} a_i/K}
$$
Let function $H(x)=x e^{-x/K}$, where $x=\sum_{i\in S} a_i$. It is straightforward to verify that $H(x)$ is increasing in $x$ for $x\leq K$; it is decreasing in $x$ for $x\geq K$. Therefore, it has the unique maximum at $x=K$, i.e., $H(x)\leq H(K)=K/e$. Then,
$$
\frac{\sum_{i\in S} a_i}{\Pi_{i\in S} b_i}= \sum_{i\in S} a_i \cdot e^{-\sum_{i\in S} a_i/K} \leq \max_x H(x)=K/e.
$$
Thus, the original problem maximized if and only if there exists a subset $S$ such that $\sum_{i\in S} a_i =K$, which is the solution to the **Partition** problem.

Comment: But if the problem is NP-complete my algorithm is wrong or not polynomial time (unless we have proved NP=P)?

Comment: If my proof is correct, I think you algorithm is still a good approximation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: My algorithm is supposed to compute the exact solution not an approximation. So either your or my proof is wrong (or we have proven P=NP)

Comment: I found an error in my algorithm. So I dont have a polynomial time algorithm. Your argument seems correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Original proof was wrong and I couldn't fix it. The algorithm does not work in general.

For $S\subset [n]$ let $a_S=\sum_{i\in S} a_i$, $b_S=\prod_{i\in S} b_i$ and $c_S=a_S/b_S$. If $S$ is optimal, $i \in S$ and $j\in [n]\backslash S$ we have
$$\frac{a_S}{b_S}=c_{S}\geq c_{(S\backslash i)\cup j}=\frac{a_S-a_i+a_j}{b_Sb_j/b_i}$$
Hence $a_S(b_j-b_i)\geq b_i(a_j-a_i)$ and therefore
$$\begin{cases} a_S\geq \frac{(a_j-a_i)b_i}{b_j-b_i} & \text{if } b_i>b_j\\ a_S\leq\frac{(a_j-a_i)b_i}{b_j-b_i} & \text{if } b_i<b_j\\ a_j\leq a_i & \text{if }b_i=b_j\end{cases}.$$
The values $\frac{(a_j-a_i)b_i}{b_j-b_i}$ for all pairs $(i,j)\in [n]^2$ divide $\mathbb{R}$ into maximal $2\binom{n}{2}+1$ many intervals. We loop through all these intervals and assume each time that $a_S$ lies in the corresponding interval. If an inequality above is violated we get that $i\in S \Rightarrow j \in S$. We consider a directed graphs with vertex set $[n]/\sim$ with $i\sim j$ iff $(a_i,b_i)=(a_j,b_j)$ and a edge from $i$ to $j$ iff $i\in S \Rightarrow j \in S$. Originally I presented a wrong proof where the graph had an edge between any two vertices and one could continue with that.